# Checking command arguments for errors from gulpfile using yargs

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have a gulpfile for an Angular app that I'm trying to catch errors in the arguments.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var args = require('yargs').argv;
...
var isProduction = args.env === 'production';
var useHttpBackend = args.api === 'mock';
```

In my gulpfile I have various tasks that use 'isProduction' and 'useHttpBackend' to determine what to do with files, assets, etc.

The two main tasks are 'default' and 'build'.

```
// Starts test server and sets up watch and livereload
gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.start('connect', 'build', 'watch');
});

...

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function() {
  gulp.start('assets', 'app', 'stylus', 'index', 'templates', 'vendor');
});
```

There's basically two commands that can be run:

```
# continuous incremental rebuild + web server + api mocking
./node_modules/.bin/gulp --api mock
...
# build for production (optimized version)
./node_modules/.bin/gulp --env production
```

I'm not even sure all this info is needed for my question, but how can I check arguments in the commands? When running the first command with '-api' (single-hyphen) instead of '--api' (double-hyphen) tasks are still run but the app does not run properly because args are not recognized. How can I ouput --help or an error in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately this in all in the specs. Please refer to [https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs#tell-users-how-to-use-yer-options-and-make-demands).

An example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('args', function(){
    require('yargs')
      .usage('Usage: $0 -w [num] -h[num]')
      .demand(['w','h'])
      .argv;

      console.log("The area is:", argv.w * argv.h);
});
```

When you do a:

```
gulp t -w 55 -h 11
```

it will result in: *The area is: 605*.

When you do a:

```
gulp t -w 55
```

it will result in an error, like:

> Usage: node ...\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js -w [num] -yh[num]
>
> Options:   -w  [required]   -h  [required]
>
> Missing required arguments: h